# Regular Grammar

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, regular-language, context-free-grammar

Devise a regular grammar in normal form that generates the language L.
Let L be the language consisting of all binary numbers
divisible by 4. 
I know the different aspects needed to be generated:
starting point, non terminals and production rules etc.
Need help on how to generate though

Comment: hint you need to generate $\{1*\}00$ strings

Comment: @zwim Would be in form {p  w  q | p E {1}*,  w E{1,0}* , q^n E {0} , n>=2 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary string is divisible by 4 if and only if it is $0$ or ends in $00$.

So, you could pretty easily do something like
$$
\begin{align*}
S&\rightarrow0\\
S&\rightarrow 1N\\
N&\rightarrow 0N\\
N&\rightarrow 0F\\
F&\rightarrow0
\end{align*}
$$
Explanation:

Our underlying alphabet (set of terminals) is $\{0,1\}$. $S$ is our start, $N$ is a non-terminal representing the part of any such non-zero number that follows the initial $1$, and $F$ is a non-terminal indicating that we've put in the first of our two final $0$'s.

From $S$ you either go straight to $0$ and are done, or you have an initial $1$.  Following an initial $1$ is any number of $0$'s and $1$'s, followed by a final $00$.